# RichTextBox setting Xaml Property Content in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, richtextbox

I have the following piece of code i made-up the purpose being this is used in a DataTemplate of a ListBox

```
<RichTextBox Name="RichTextBoxPostContent" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0" Padding="8,8,8,0" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Xaml="{Binding PostContent}" AcceptsReturn="True" />
```

where the Xaml property gets set by the xaml content ( a string ) thats comes from the database.

Now i have wired javascript error when i try to set the xaml

this is the xaml content im trying to set RichTextBox.Xaml to,

```
<Section xml:space="preserve" HasTrailingParagraphBreakOnPaste="False" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph FontSize="11" FontFamily="Portable User Interface" Foreground="#FF000000" FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" TextAlignment="Left"><Run FontSize="31" Text="This" /><Run Text=" " /><Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="is" /><Run Text=" " /><Run FontSize="26" FontStyle="Italic" Text="a" /><Run Text=" " /><Run FontWeight="Normal" FontStyle="Italic" Text="test " /><Run Text="post " /><Hyperlink Foreground="#FF337CBB" TextDecorations="Underline" NavigateUri="http://google.com" MouseOverForeground="#FFED6E00"><Run Text=":)" /></Hyperlink></Paragraph></Section>
```

any help is greatly appropriated, thanks!

Comment: I guess Silverlight RichTextBox has some bugs to be fixed it doesn't behave like WPF's RichTextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an awesome solution for this at this Location hope this helps everyone dealing with my issue with Silverlight RichTextBox
http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/asills/archive/2010/11/17/fun-with-attached-properties-%E2%80%93-bindable-richtextbox-xaml.aspx